# multiple knockout bindings and sharing them

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, sammy.js

So I have a scenario where I am have knockout binding on my main page.

Index.cshtml:

```
<div data-bind="foreach breadcrumbs">
<div>

<script>
 var IndexViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.breadcrumbs = ko.observableArray();
 };
 ko.applyBindings(IndexViewModel);
</script>
```

And a Partial View that loads inside the Index.cshtml. The partial view has its own knockout bindings:

```
<div id="someId">

</div>
<script>
  var PartialViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.someFunction = function(){
            // Access Breadcrumbs here
        };
  };
  ko.applyBindings(PartialViewModel, "someId");
</script>
```

I want to access the breadcrumbs observableArray from the second partial view and add items to them. I am not even sure if this possible. Please help. I am also using sammy.js but for this purpose its not that relevant.

Comment: Your scripts will not work. You need to call the ViewModel constructor functions with new.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like having to have dependencies between view models, so I've previously used a jQuery pubsub plugin to allow view models to talk to each other in a decoupled manner. You can see an example of it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555381/variable-dependency-with-knockoutjs/14559492#14559492)

Basically, when you update the breadcrumb, call publish with the new array, and the other view model would subscribe to that event.

Comment: If you are doing pubsub in KO between VMs, then you might want to look at the postbox plugin that I created here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox. It has some observable extensions that make it easy to automatically publish/subscribe to changes in observables through a mediator.

Comment: Good point. I did look at it when I was doing this originally, but for that project I needed to do a lot more with each event, hence going with pubsub. Your plugin would be ideal for this scenario, you are correct. :)

Comment: is knockout-postbox compatible with knockout 2.2.0? I have included the lib in my source, but keep on getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'subscribe' of undefined @RPNiemeyer

Comment: Postbox is compatible with 2.2. Sounds like you might have something else going on. If you have a repro, feel free to send me an email ryan at knockmeout.net

Comment: @RPNiemeyer I figured it out. PEBCAK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution (**but not very clean one**) would be to store the indexViewModel in a global variable.

Index.cshtml:

```
 var IndexViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.breadcrumbs = ko.observableArray();
 };
 // we create a global variable here
 window.indexViewModel = new IndexViewModel();

 ko.applyBindings(window.indexViewModel);
```

And then you can access this indexViewModel from your partial view model:

```
  var PartialViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.someFunction = function(){
            // Access Breadcrumbs here
            // better use some wrapping functions 
            // instead of accessing the array directly
            window.indexViewModel.breadcrumbs.push({}); 
        };
  };
  ko.applyBindings(new PartialViewModel(), "someId");
</script>
```