# KnockoutJs What is best way to fire event between two models?

Tags: knockout.js

I have 2 objects on one page, and I would like to fire some event in model 2 after some changes in model 1. What is the best and right way to do it ?
Would be nice to get some example thanks

Comment: Flagged as duplicate, look at this answer (and the comments for an alternative): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606313/multiple-knockout-bindings-and-sharing-them/14606443#14606443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this using my convention library, it has a util function for finding the name of a constructor. This way it hides all magic strings and appear to be strongly typed for the user. Use it like this

Subscribe

```
MyApp.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.DeleteCustomerMessage, this.customerDeleted.bind(this));
```

Publish

```
MyApp.eventAggregator.publish(new MyApp.DeleteCustomerMessage(this));
```

MyApp.eventAggregator is a instance on the global namespace so the message will fire globaly, you can also instance a local instance of MyApp.EventAggregator and use it for a sub set of view models

Fully working example can be seen here
http://jsfiddle.net/wJtun/

**edit:** You can actually do it without my lib too
http://jsfiddle.net/wJtun/4/

**Note:** In the simple example above we have a possible memory leak, if you remove the reference to the subscribed ViewModel it wont get garbage collected because the EventAggregator holds a reference to it. So if you for example are in a SPA scenario you need to implement a unsubscribe method that remove the reference (Weak references are not possible with Javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use AmplifyJS http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/ to call one model from another without coupling them.