# KnockoutJS multiple view models and 'breaking out' of one

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

So I'm working with multiple view models using KnockoutJS, like this:

```
function firstViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.dataArray = ko.observableArray([
        { title: "title1", theData: "data1" },
        { title: "title2", theData: "data2" },
        { title: "title3", theData: "data3" },
    ]);
};

function secondViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.addData = function() {
        firstViewModel.dataArray.push({ title: "newTitle", theData: "newData" });
        // trying to trigger dataArray in firstViewModel, doesn't work
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new firstViewModel(), document.getElementById('first'));
ko.applyBindings(new secondViewModel(), document.getElementById('second'));
```

Then something like:

```
<div id="first" data-bind="with: dataArray">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <li data-bind="text: theData"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <button data-bind="click: addData">add</button>
</div>
```

The reason it's structured like this is because I have a 3rd view model and the elements overlap in the DOM. I couldn't figure out how to get [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html) to work either.

Is there any way to keep the structure and reference firstViewModel inside of secondViewModel? *firstViewModel.theData.push("newData");* clearly doesn't work, but I thought I'd include it to further clarify what I'm looking to do.

I'm brand new to KO - sorry if it's a stupid question.

**EDIT:** Looks like I got it!

If I remove 'self' from the firstViewModel it works...

```
dataArray = ko.observableArray([
    { title: "title1", theData: "data1" },
    { title: "title2", theData: "data2" }
]);
```

then

```
self.addData = function() {
    dataArray.push({ title: "newTitle", theData: "newData" });
}
```

I don't know yet if there are consequences of removing the 'self', but it's working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to keep my models de-coupled, and use a publish/subscribe pattern to allow them to talk to each other. See my answer to [Variable Dependency with knockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555381/variable-dependency-with-knockoutjs/14559492#14559492)

In addition, if you do want to go down that road, you can also look at [knockout postbox](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/&ei=7Kg5UdLxMaLL0AXQsYCQCw&usg=AFQjCNG-FzUVJ5Y20TdRgrG8dZv1CVv4og&sig2=1o7hkt8cMVaEEaR79sXdLQ&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k) to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference of the first viewmodel:

```
function firstViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.dataArray = ko.observableArray([
        { title: "title1", theData: "data1" },
        { title: "title2", theData: "data2" },
        { title: "title3", theData: "data3" },
    ]);
};

function secondViewModel(firstViewModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.addData = function() {
        firstViewModel.dataArray.push({ title: "newTitle", theData: "newData" }); // doesn't work
    }
};

var firstVm = new firstViewModel();
var secondVm = new secondViewModel(firstVm);
ko.applyBindings(firstVm, document.getElementById('first'));
ko.applyBindings(secondVm, document.getElementById('second'));
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. 'firstViewModel.dataArray is undefined' when I try that.